# Android Sqlite table has more than one primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

this below code is my database schema and after run `onCreate` method i get this error:

```
08-28 08:13:23.984    3214-3214/ir.tsms E/Database﹕ Failure 1 (table "ReceiveFields" has more than one primary key) on 0x1175f8 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE ReceiveFields(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, lastId INTEGER  , smsNumber VARCHAR  , mobileNumber VARCHAR , senderName VARCHAR , smsBody TEXT , receiveDate VARCHAR , PRIMARY KEY (id));'.
```

DataBase create Schema Variable:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE + "("
        + COLUMN_ID +            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COLUMN_LASTID +        " INTEGER  , "
        + COLUMN_SMSNUMBER +     " VARCHAR  , "
        + COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER +  " VARCHAR , "
        + COLUMN_SENDERNAME +    " VARCHAR , "
        + COLUMN_SMSBODY +       " TEXT , "
        + COLUMN_RECEIVEDATE +   " VARCHAR , PRIMARY KEY (" + COLUMN_ID + "));";
```

`Log.i` Result of `DATABASE_CREATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE ReceiveFields(

    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, 
    lastId INTEGER  , 
    smsNumber VARCHAR  , 
    mobileNumber VARCHAR , 
    senderName VARCHAR , 
    smsBody TEXT , 
    receiveDate VARCHAR , 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
```

whats my create table problem? thanks

Comment: take out one of the `PRIMARY KEY` clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `PRIMARY KEY (" + COLUMN_ID + ")` from the end of `DATABASE_CREATE` query string.
change your code to:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE + "("
    + COLUMN_ID +            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + COLUMN_LASTID +        " INTEGER  , "
    + COLUMN_SMSNUMBER +     " VARCHAR  , "
    + COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER +  " VARCHAR , "
    + COLUMN_SENDERNAME +    " VARCHAR , "
    + COLUMN_SMSBODY +       " TEXT , "
    + COLUMN_RECEIVEDATE +   " VARCHAR );";
```

Comment: i want to my `COLUMN_ID` was `PRIMARY KEY` can i have?

Comment: Yes you can. Just insert `PRIMARY KEY` statement where you define a field. for example you can use: `... COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ...`